# Plotting histograms against classes in pandas / matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

Is there a idiomatic way to plot the histogram of a feature for two classes?
In pandas, I basically want

```
df.feature[df.class == 0].hist()
df.feature[df.class == 1].hist()
```

To be in the same plot. I could do

```
df.feature.hist(by=df.class)
```

but that gives me two separate plots.

This seems to be a common task so I would imagine there to be an idiomatic way to do this. Of course I could manipulate the histograms manually to fit next to each other but usually pandas does that quite nicely.

Basically I want this matplotlib example in one line of pandas: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo.html

I thought I was missing something, but maybe it is not possible (yet).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about `df.groupby("class").feature.hist()`? To see overlapping distributions you'll probably need to pass `alpha=0.4` to `hist()`. Alternatively, I'd be tempted to use a kernel density estimate instead of a histogram with `df.groupby("class").feature.plot(kind='kde')`.

As an example, I plotted the iris dataset's classes using:

```
iris.groupby("Name").PetalWidth.plot(kind='kde', ax=axs[1])
iris.groupby("Name").PetalWidth.hist(alpha=0.4, ax=axs[0])
```

[image]

Comment: What is the `axs` list supposed to refer to?

Comment: A list of matplotlib axes generated with something like `fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2)`. See the docs: http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html#easily-creating-subplots

Comment: To get consistent spacing for the histogram, one needs to specify `range=[df. PetalWidth.min(), df. PetalWidth.max()]`.

Comment: Thanks!  How can we get a legend for the colors in the boxplot?

Comment: Add one to the axis object. For example, `axs[1].legend()` is probably what was used in the example there.

Comment: `axs[1].legend()` complains about no handles if used on the histogram. For the KDE plot you can pass `legend=True`